# React Hooks: updating state using useState does not update the state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form that has various fields, and one of the fields contains an array of objects.

It pretty much adds an object that contains values from a subform of the main form.

```
const addNode = () => {
    let p_form = pForm
    let ha = [vForm, yForm, hForm]
    let info = [....]
    setCurrentNodeForm(
        {
            ...currentNodeForm,
            p: p_form,
            ha: ha,
            info: info,
        }
    )
    // inserts this form to a state called `addedNodes`
    let currArr = [...addedNodes]
    currArr.push(currentNodeForm)
    setAddedNodes(currArr)
    intializeForms()
}
```

This is the function that I use as an `onClick` function of my `Add` button.

This adds a new object to a state called `addedNodes` which is an array of objects.

Then when I submit my main form, I use the function below as an `onClick` function

```
const submitMainForm = () => {
    let credentials = [...]
    let nodes = [...addedNodes]
    setMainForm(
        {
            ...currentMainForm,
            credentials: credentials,
            nodes: nodes,
        }
    )

    let body = {
        name: .... // something
        objects: currentMainForm,
    }

    intializeForms()

    let options = {
        headers: header,
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    }

    console.log('options.body', options.body)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(endpoint, options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(resText => {
                console.log('resText', resText)
            })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

What it does is, it updates the state `currentMainForm` using the current `addedNodes` object array that I have updated using the `addNode` function above. However, when I `console.log` the `options.body` as shown above, the `objects` field in the `body` is empty. Thus, when I send a `POST` request, the `body` is missing its critical part.

When I `console.log` the same thing outside the function, it shows up.

I wonder how I can guarantee the state to be updated properly inside the function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the side effect in `React hook`. if it's a functional component then add the api call in `useEffect` hook.

`setMainForm` is an async function, because of it's `async` nature you are getting no data in body.

What you can do, update the state in submit function, and use the `useEffect` hook to listen the change on the `currentMainForm` state and submit your data.

**Example**

```
useEffect( () => {
  fetchData();
}, [currentMainForm]);

const submitMainForm = () => {
  let credentials = [...]
  let nodes = [...addedNodes]
  setMainForm( prevState => {
    return  {
      ...currentMainForm,
      credentials: credentials,
      nodes: nodes,
    }
  });
}

function fetchData() {
  let body = {
    name: '....', // something
    objects: currentMainForm,
  }

  intializeForms()

  let options = {
      headers: header,
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
  }

  console.log('options.body', options.body)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(endpoint, options)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(resText => {
              console.log('resText', resText)
          })
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  })
}
```